# Python Loop replace a part of string

Tags: python, pandas, function, jupyter-notebook

I am making a project using Jupyter Notebook. I am creating an oversimplified example here.

I have a url,  lets say

```
url=www.instagram.com/alex
```

I need to create a database by adding `url` with `replace` function in column adjacent to names
And I have a pandas data frame

```
Names
John
Cherry 
nancy
```

Results wanted using function

```
Names    url
John     wwww.instagram.com/john
Cherry   www.instagram.com/cherry
nancy    www.instagram.com/nancy
```

What I am doing is:

```
data["url"] = url
w = data.names.values
def replace()
   for i in w,data.iteritems:
      for j in range(len(data.url),data.iteritems:
         data["url"]=url.replace("alex",i(j))
         return data
```

It throws an error that I cannot use `range` as indices... so I tried many things to use integers, but it still doesn't give me the results until I manually put i(0) or i(1) or i(3)
If I try to add another for line like

```
for w in range(len(data.url):
```

And do i(w)..
Then it changes everything to the i(0) that in this example will be [www.instagram.com/john](http://www.instagram.com/john)

I have used oversimplified example for my problem, in my project it is very important to create function because url is too big and the names are input (user selects) so that is why i need to creaTe function

Comment: data["url"] = "www.instagram.com/" + data["Names"].str.lower() ...                                          
  this cannot work because my orignal url is  something like this....   www.instagram.com/abshcuenduejsjdj#ALEX20ndj/jsjejjsjdjdb/jejehudbehdj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below:

```
df['url'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x : url.replace('alex',x.lower()))
```

Comment: `x.lower()` rather than just `x`.

Answer (score 1):

```
data["url"] = "www.instagram.com/" + data["Names"].str.lower()
```

Comment: Thanks for response  ... this cannot work because my orignal url is something like this.... www.instagram.com/abshcuenduejsjdj#ALEX20ndj/jsjejjsjdjdb/jejehudbehd